# How to display flot chart crosshair values in a <div> tag?

Tags: javascript, flot

Being given this example: http://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/k9FkZ/, how could I display sin and cos values in a `<div></div>`? I tried to append y like:     `$("#h2").eq(i).html(y.toFixed(2));` and `H2: <div id="h2" />`, but didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you already are displaying sin and cos values?

Comment: I display the values in the legend. I wanna display those values above the graphic, in div tag.

Comment: I really don't realize how to show the values in a div, or in two separate div tags.

Comment: You could, perhaps, change your loop to contain something among the lines of [`$("#h" + (i + 1)).html(y.toFixed(2));`](http://jsfiddle.net/k9FkZ/17/). :)

Comment: That worked like a charm! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9FkZ/18/) for a working version.

Added to the HTML:

```
<div id="h1"></div>
<div id="h2"></div>
```

Added to the `updateLegend` function:

```
    $('#h' + (i + 1).toString()).html(series.label.replace(/=.*/, "= " + y.toFixed(2)));
```